# Ethereum keeps showing token value as 0

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am in the initial phase of learning ethereum. I am testing smart contract using Ropsten Testnet. When I transfer my coin to some other it shows that token value is 0. Is there any way to set the token price?

It was showing like this

```
Value: 0 Ether ($0.00)
```

[image]

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ethereum keeps showing token value as 0

The screenshot in the question is of a website called Etherscan, which should not be confused with the core Ethereum protocol or network. The website, which is run by a private company, analyses the network and provides a summary.

> Is there any way to set the token price?

The `value` that you highlighted is the amount of ether sent with a transaction. Any token transfer that does not include ether with have a "0 value" in that place. In the line above, you can see that Etherscan detected and displayed that 10 tokens were transferred.

If you want Etherscan to display something different, you would have to take it up with their company. (Although I wouldn't count on them accommodating custom requests)

Comment: Thank you very much @carver for such detailed explanation.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to control the price of our token? I mean how can I set the price of my token? through sdk or smart contract?